# Merging multiple arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that supposed to merge 3 arrays based on a matching `siteid`.

This works to an extend. Basically, it only finds 1 siteid and ignores the Same siteides!

This is the code:

if you run the code below, you see that it only adds one of the forms with **siteid of 77** to the merged Array! but it should add all the forms with the same siteid (77 in this example) to the merged array.

```
var siteS1 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];


var siteS2 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

var form = [{
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

const merge = (...arrayList) => {
  const siteids = arrayList
    .map(array => array.map(item => item.siteid))
    .flat()
  return Array.from(new Set(siteids))
}

const find = (siteid, array) => {
  const found = array.find(item => item.siteid === siteid)
  if (!found) return undefined // returns undefined if item was not found
  const {
    siteid: _,
    ...restFoundData
  } = found // omit `siteid` from found item
  return restFoundData
}

const populate = (siteids) => siteids.map(siteid => {
  const foundSiteS1 = find(siteid, siteS1)
  const foundSiteS2 = find(siteid, siteS2)
  const foundForm = find(siteid, form)
  return {
    siteS1: foundSiteS1,
    siteS2: foundSiteS2,
    form: foundForm ? [foundForm.data] : [], // empty array if no items matched
  }
})

const result = populate(merge(siteS1, siteS2, form))
console.log(result)
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

Here is the example code:

```
var siteS1 = [{
Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
siteid: 77,
}];


var siteS2 = [{
Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
siteid: 77,
}];

var form = [{
data: {},
siteid: 77,
},
{
data: {},
siteid: 77,
},
{
data: {},
siteid: 77,
},
{
data: {},
siteid: 77,
},
{
data: {},
siteid: 78,
}];
```

The expected result is this:

```
[{
    "siteS1": {
        "Date": "2021-02-02 11:19"
    },
    "siteS2": {
        "Date": "2021-02-02 11:19"
    },
    "form": [{},{},{},{}]
}]
```

But the current code's results is this:

```
[{
    "siteS1": {
        "Date": "2021-02-02 11:19"
    },
    "siteS2": {
        "Date": "2021-02-02 11:19"
    },
    "form": [{}]
}]
```

as you can see, it only finds 1 of the forms with the siteid of 77 and ignores the rest.

Comment: A lot of code... Data are not related to the question. can you sum it up?

Comment: Can you add some expected output please?

Comment: Please add an example of *expected output* as per the help center. I appreciate you sharing your attempt to solve it yourself but it's ... difficult to follow.

Comment: `array.find` finds first matching element only

Comment: @Ameer, Please view my edit.

Comment: @JaredSmith, please view my edit.

Comment: Could you explain the form part of the object on line 8 of the last example?

Comment: @luekbaja, the form holds an array. I've left it empty for simplicity sake and also, it could be an empty array so this has to be considered.

Comment: @AvivBenShahar, nothing's missing in the code! not sure what you see! but if you copy/paste the same code in jsfiddle, you should see the result in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.find` finds first matching element only, I use another function to find all matching data for the form

```
const findAll = (siteid, array) => {
    return array.filter(item => item.siteid === siteid).map(({siteid, ...data}) => data);
}
```

```js
var siteS1 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];


var siteS2 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

var form = [{
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

const merge = (...arrayList) => {
  const siteids = arrayList
    .map(array => array.map(item => item.siteid))
    .flat()
  return Array.from(new Set(siteids))
}

const find = (siteid, array) => {
  const found = array.find(item => item.siteid === siteid)
  if (!found) return undefined // returns undefined if item was not found
  const {
    siteid: _,
    ...restFoundData
  } = found // omit `siteid` from found item
  return restFoundData
}

const findAll = (siteid, array) => {
  return array.filter(item => item.siteid === siteid).map(({siteid, ...data}) => data);
}

const populate = (siteids) => siteids.map(siteid => {
  const foundSiteS1 = find(siteid, siteS1)
  const foundSiteS2 = find(siteid, siteS2)
  const foundForm = findAll(siteid, form)
  return {
    siteS1: foundSiteS1,
    siteS2: foundSiteS2,
    form: foundForm, // empty array if no items matched
  }
})

const result = populate(merge(siteS1, siteS2, form))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That is a lot of looping :)

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few things here...

First lets get the matching site ids from the two arrays:

```js
const ids = [
    ...siteS1.map(({ siteid }) => siteid),
    ...siteS2.map(({ siteid }) => siteid),
].filter((x, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) !== i); // non-unique, i.e. in both arrays
```

Ok, now we need the entries from `form`:

```js
const results = ids.map(id => {
    return {
       siteS1: {
           Date: siteS1.find(({ siteid }) => siteid === id).Date,
       },
       siteS2: {
           Date: siteS2.find(({ siteid }) => siteid === id).Date,
       }
       form: form.filter(({ siteid }) => siteid === id),
    };
});
```

That will give you your result for every site id in both arrays in an array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle is is creating maps by id so you can easily look up data. This is so you are not constantly looping over arrays trying to find all of the things that match.

```js
var siteS1 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];


var siteS2 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

var form = [{
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

const keyBySiteIdDate = (sites) => sites.reduce((acc, site) => {
  acc[site.siteid] = site.Date;
  return acc;
}, {});

const keyBySiteIdData = (sites) => sites.reduce((acc, site) => {
  acc[site.siteid] = acc[site.siteid] || [];
  acc[site.siteid].push(site.data);
  return acc;
}, {});


const sitesKeyed1 = keyBySiteIdDate(siteS1);
const sitesKeyed2 = keyBySiteIdDate(siteS2);
const dataKeyed = keyBySiteIdData(form);

// as an array
const result = Object.entries(sitesKeyed1).map(([siteId, date]) => {
  if (sitesKeyed2[siteId]) {
    return {
      siteId,
      siteS1: date,
      siteS2: sitesKeyed2[siteId],
      form: dataKeyed[siteId] || [],
    }
  }
  return null;
}).filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);

// as an object
const result2 = Object.entries(sitesKeyed1).reduce((acc, [siteId, date]) => {
  if (sitesKeyed2[siteId]) {
    acc[siteId] = {
      siteS1: date,
      siteS2: sitesKeyed2[siteId],
      form: dataKeyed[siteId] || [],
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result2);
```

This assumes the values are in both arrays. If they can be in one or the other and you need that data, it is a bit more looping, but it is doable.

```js
var siteS1 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  }
];


var siteS2 = [{
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 66,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 96,
  },
  {
    Date: '2021-02-02 11:19',
    siteid: 11111111111,
  }
];

var form = [{
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 77,
  },
  {
    data: {},
    siteid: 96,
  }
];

const keyBySiteIdDate = (sites) => sites.reduce((acc, site) => {
  acc[site.siteid] = site.Date;
  return acc;
}, {});

const keyBySiteIdData = (sites) => sites.reduce((acc, site) => {
  acc[site.siteid] = acc[site.siteid] || [];
  acc[site.siteid].push(site.data);
  return acc;
}, {});


const sitesKeyed1 = keyBySiteIdDate(siteS1);
const sitesKeyed2 = keyBySiteIdDate(siteS2);
const dataKeyed = keyBySiteIdData(form);

const uniqueSiteIds = Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(sitesKeyed1).concat(Object.keys(sitesKeyed2))]).values())

const result = uniqueSiteIds.map(siteId => ({
  siteId,
  siteS1: sitesKeyed1[siteId],
  siteS2: sitesKeyed2[siteId],
  form: dataKeyed[siteId] || [],
}));

console.log(result);


// as an object
const result2 = uniqueSiteIds.reduce((acc, siteId) => {
  acc[siteId] = {
    siteS1: sitesKeyed1[siteId],
    siteS2: sitesKeyed2[siteId],
    form: dataKeyed[siteId] || [],
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not the best solution but it's the first thing i thought

```js
[...new Set([...siteS1, ...siteS2, ...forms].map(s => s.siteid))].map(id => ({
    siteS1: siteS1.find(s => s.siteid === id);
    siteS2: siteS2.find(s => s.siteid === id);
    form: form.filter(f => f.siteid === id);
}));
```

Comment: What if the id isn't present in both of the initial arrays?

Comment: He didn't say anything about except for the form array, i fixed that

Comment: No I mean if the id isn't in both siteS arrays `.find` isn't going to return anything for the one it's not in. And for form OP apparently wants *all* the matches, so `.find` isn't going to work for that one.

Comment: If the id isn't present in both of the arrays it returns undefined and that makes sense so when you work with the result you know that that siteid was present only in one of the two sites array. The function should just join them and say 'Ok in this array it's present this id but not in the other', after that it's your turn. If the function doesn't give back elements if one of the two arrays doesn't contain an id you will think that none of them had that id

Comment: And for the form array i fixed that, also i want to say that this is may personal approach and as i wrote in the first line, this probably won't be the best solution, it's literaly the first thing i thought when i saw this question

Answer (score 1):

To merge two arrays, normally you want to have them sorted first.
Once sorted, the standard algorithm gives you O(n+m) complexity.

Just check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/ they have done good job explaining it.